# Allowing multiple users to join a chatroom (using Django, Socket.io and node.js)

Tags: django, node.js, socket.io, chat

I followed [this tutorial](http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/) and I created my own database, etc. I was able to run the above example successfully but I realized, it's just the barebones of what a chat encompasses.

Has anyone actually implemented a multi-user chat room with Django, Socket.io and Node.js?

Looking through the code, I essentially created a superuser/admin and now I can log in and log out. However, how do I create a log in for anyone to use to implement the chat and how do I get them to join the chatroom?

Thanks in advance.

Any direction to a tutorial, documentation or personal experience would be great.

Comment: There are quite a few examples at the gevent-socketio docs: https://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the django chat on their example to work. I'm getting this error on ubuntu: "Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
zc.buildout 2 needs distribute, not setuptools.  Are you using an outdated bootstrap.py?  Make sure you have the latest version downloaded from http://downloads.buildout.org/2/bootstrap.py
" and when I directed to that link, I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to look for @_@;

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for multiple chat room ! 
you can use .in() and .join() for connecting new chat rooms and connecting users to specific rooms !